# Centos Docker : Connection reset by peer

Tags: azure, docker, nginx, centos, centos7

I run nginx container on my azure Vm, centos 7 with this command:

`docker run --name nginx2 --detach -p 0.0.0.0:90:80 nginx`

Now If I run this command on the host machine: `curl localhost:90` I got the error:

`curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`

**What I tried:**

1. On my local machine

I follow the same steps on my local machine and everything works like a charm. So the nginx image is not the problem

2. Inside the container

On my VM, I connect to the nginx container and run the command : `curl localhost:80` and got the answer. So nginx listen on port 80.

3. From another container

If I create a second container and run the command `curl <nginx-ip>:80`. I got the result. So nginx not listen only on localhost, but on all ip.

4. host network

When I run the container using Host Newtork `--network host`, everything work fine. But I don't want to do that

5. Try with another container
   I try using this container: `docker run -p 8000:8000 -it python:3.7-slim python3 -m http.server --bind 0.0.0.0`. But same error.

My question is what is the problem with bridge network on Centos ?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem with CentOS 7.1 and latest Docker 19.03.

Only way I was able to resolve this was to revert to Docker 18.03 (other versions might also work). After uninstalling current Docker I installed earlier version:
`yum install docker-ce-18.03.1.ce-1.el7.centos`

After this `curl localhost:<port>` started to work ok with the nginx.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with 3000 and 80 port, add your ports to the firewal records like that:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --change-interface=docker0
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-port=80/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-port=90/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload
```

also check if you have iptables - disable it

```
systemctl disable iptables.service
```